# Wiremock is returning A JSONObject text must begin with &apos;{&apos; at 0 [character 1 line 1]

Tags: wiremock

My wiremock req:

```
 wireMockServer.stubFor(
                get(urlMatching("/path"))
                        .withQueryParam("car", matching("^.*$"))
                        .withHeader("X", matching("\\d+")).
                        withHeader("X", matching("\\d+")).
                        withHeader("accept", matching("\\S+"))
                        .willReturn(
                                aResponse()
                                        .withStatus(200)
                                        .withStatusMessage("OK")
                                        .withBody("")
                                        .withTransformers("xyz")));
```

Transformer:

```
if (requestUrl.toLowerCase().contains("path")) {
    return ResponseDefinitionBuilder.like(responseDefinition)
            .but()
            .withBodyFile(null)
            .withBody("{\"Details\":[{\"Number\":\"string\",\"LocationName\":\"string\"}]}")
            .build();
}
```

But i am getting error "A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 0 [character 1 line 1]"

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `.withBodyFile(null)`?

Comment: no, still getting same error

Comment: Where is this error being thrown from? Is it WireMock or your client code?